# How to use domain model relations in viewmodel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using viewmodel in order to separate domain model from data presentation, but I can't get how to use database table relations that exist in domain model.
For example this domain model class how should be used in viewmodel? In this exanple CurrencyDictionary is the table with foreign key for Settings table.

```
public partial class Settings
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...List of properties...
    public int ShopCurrency { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CurrencyList { get; set; }     
    public virtual CurrencyDictionary CurrencyDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use AutoMapper OR project out to the dto...

Comment: @CallumLinington, I consider that as well, but I found that it's not completely reliable.

Comment: What isn't reliable?

Comment: Here is good article explaining what I mean - http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code

Comment: That is old - EF 4.1 Code First - its talking about 2 versions of EF ago, there have been vast improvements in EF 6 alone. If you're worried about the way it projects then do some small tests... don't just read someones blog and run for the hills - what is to say they're right? have you tested his code?

Comment: I did not. So you mean that AutoMapper can handle such kind of things as well?

Comment: AutoMapper was built for the purpose of Mapping domain => DTO (or what ever you want to call it). The idea is to take out the mundane task of projecting by hand. It can either project from an IQueryable (thus dictating the SQL sent to the database) or on anything that implements IEnumerable (so in memory objects). I strongly suggest you try it out to convince yourself it will do what you expect

Comment: @CallumLinington, please add your post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have a corresponding view model for any given domain model that is related, So your `Settings` view model would contain a corresponding `CurrencyDictionary` view model, something like:

```
public class SettingsModel
{
    public CurrencyDictionaryModel CurrencyDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's was first what I did. Unfortunately: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CurrencyDictionary_E57C33C3604D4873EA0EA9F0ADE809ECC0E6BC70DF9C7695DC2E569D6C584C60' type to the 'DigitalHubOnlineStore.ViewModels.CurrencyDictionaryViewModel' type is not valid.

Comment: @andrey.shedko You shouldn't be casting to your view model type from your domain model type, you have to create a new instance of the view model and populate it with the domain model. Post the code in question and I'll give you the proper query.